# Angular 1.5 - How to add element to a scoped array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an Angular controller that defines a scoped variable that consist of an array of objects. Each object is a tagName and its value is a list of services associated to those tags:

```
$scope.recordedServices = [{"myTag" : [{ url : "http://service0"}, { url : "http://service1" }] }];
```

After the page is loaded `{{recordedServices}}` prints correctly:

```
[{"myTag":[{"url":"http://service0"},{"url":"http://service1"}]}]
```

In that controller I have a `replaceList` function that replaces the whole `$scoped.recordedServices` list:

```
  $scope.replaceList = function(){
      $scope.recordedServices = [ {"myTag" : [{url:"http://replacedList"}] }];
  }
```

When calling it, everything works as expected, `{{recordedServices}}` is now:

```
[{"myTag":[{"url":"http://replacedList"}]}]
```

Now the problem. What I really want to do is add a new service to "myTag":

```
  $scope.addToList = function(){
      $scope.recordedServices["myTag"].push({url:"http://addedService"});
  }
```

But it fails because `$scope.recordedServices["myTag"]` doesn't exist, the actual structure of the `$scoped.recordedServices` list is:

```
$scope.recordedServices: Array[1]
0 : Object
  $$hashKey : "object:33"
  myTag : Array[1]
    0 : Object
      $$hashKey : "object:36"
      url : "http://replacedList"
```

What is the correct (Angular) way to add an element to that array?

**UPDATE:**

One possible solution would be doing:

```
 $scope.addToList2 = function(){
      if($scope.recordedServices[0] == null){
          $scope.recordedServices[0] = [];
      }
      if($scope.recordedServices[0]["myTag"] == null){
          $scope.recordedServices[0]["myTag"] = [];
      }
      $scope.recordedServices[0]["myTag"].push({url:"http://addedService"});
  }
```

But this works only if `$scope.recordedServices` was initialized in the controller (for instance: `$scope.recordedServices = [{"myTag" : [{ url : "http://service0"}, { url : "http://service1" }] }];`). However if initially it is `$scope.recordedServices = []` it doesn't work.

`{{recordedServices}}` prints `[[]]`

Inspecting the variable the content is as follows. It looks similar with the only differenced that `myTag[0]` doesn't contain `$$hashKey`.

```
$scope.recordedServices: Array[1]
0 : Array[0]
  $$hashKey : "object:68"
  length : 0
  myTag : Array[1]
    0 : Object
      url : "http://addedService"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.recordedServices` is an array. You should use an index:

Change this:

```
$scope.recordedServices["myTag"].push({url:"http://addedService"});
```

to this:

```
$scope.recordedServices[0]["myTag"].push({url:"http://addedService"});
```

**UPDATE**

You can check if it is empty, if so, add `myTag` object too:

```
if ($scope.recordedServices.length == 0){
    $scope.recordedServices.push({"myTag": [{url:"http://addedService"}]});
}else{
    $scope.recordedServices[0]["myTag"].push({url:"http://addedService"});
}
```

Comment: Hi! It works when the initial list is already populated. But if $scope.recordedServices = [] initially it doesn't work. I'm updating the question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your `$scope.recordedServices=[]` as an empty array inside your controller. So now you can play with it inside the controller and view as you wish.
Push new record like this -

```
$scope.addToList = function(){
  $scope.recordedServices.push({url:"http://addedService"});
}
```